# Spresense SDK(IDE)でデバッグを行おうとするとGDBがversionエラーになる

Tags: spresense, vscode, debugging

Windows 10 Home上でSpresenseのSDK (IDE)環境を新規に構築しています。
デバッガとして公式ページに載っているLCP-Link2がほぼ入手不可能な様子なので、DAP-LinkコンパチなMCU-Linkが使えないか試すのが動機です(それができたら秋月のlPC11U35ボードも...)。単体OpenOCDで"openocd -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f target/cxd5602.cfg"でSpresenseに接続できることまでは確認しました。

・やったこと
[Spresense公式ページ](https://developer.sony.com/develop/spresense/docs/sdk_set_up_ide_ja.html)に添って新規にMSYS2(インストーラmsys2-x86_64-20220904.exe インストール後pacman -Syu実行済), Spresense SDK, VisualStudio Code(1.71.2)をインストールし、Cのソースコード(普通のHelloWorld)をコンパイル、Spresenseに転送して実行できることは確認しています。
VSCの拡張で関係ありそうなもののバージョンはこんなところです。
Spresense VSCode IDE V1.3.200
C/C++ V1.12.4
C/C++ Extension Pack V1.3.0

・起こったこと
続いて[実行とデバッグ]に入り、[デバッグの開始]をしようとしたところ、以下のエラーダイアログが表示されてデバッガに入れませんでした。
[image: エラーダイアログ]

また、デバッグコンソールには以下が表示されました。

```
Cortex-Debug: VSCode debugger extension version 1.6.5 git(ed64786). Usage info: https://github.com/Marus/cortex-debug#usage
Reading symbols from c:/msys64/opt/spresenseenv/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-objdump.exe --syms -C -h -w C:/msys64/home/User/spProjMsys1/out/spProjMsys1.nuttx 
Reading symbols from c:/msys64/opt/spresenseenv/usr/bin/arm-none-eabi-nm.exe --defined-only -S -l -C -p C:/msys64/home/User/spProjMsys1/out/spProjMsys1.nuttx 
Launching GDB: "c:\\msys64\\opt\\spresenseenv\\usr\\bin\\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe" -q --interpreter=mi2 -ix .vscode/.gdbinit 
IMPORTANT: Set "showDevDebugOutput": "raw" in "launch.json" to see verbose GDB transactions here. Very helpful to debug issues or report problems 
Launching gdb-server: "c:\\msys64\\opt\\spresenseenv\\usr\\bin\\openocd" -c "gdb_port 50000" -c "tcl_port 50001" -c "telnet_port 50002" -s "C:\\msys64\\home\\User\\spresense\\sdk\\tools" -f "c:/Users/User/.vscode/extensions/marus25.cortex-debug-1.6.5/support/openocd-helpers.tcl" -f interface/cmsis-dap.cfg -f cxd5602.cfg 
Please check TERMINAL tab (gdb-server) for output from c:\msys64\opt\spresenseenv\usr\bin\openocd 
Finished reading symbols from objdump: Time: 141 ms 
c:\msys64\opt\spresenseenv\usr\bin\arm-none-eabi-gdb.exe: warning: Couldn't determine a path for the index cache directory. 
ERROR: GDB major version should be >= 9, yours is 8 
GDB could not start as expected. Bad installation or version mismatch. See if you can start gdb from a shell prompt and check its version (Must be >= 9)
```

このとき、

```
arm-none-eabi-gdb -v
GNU gdb (GNU Tools for Arm Embedded Processors 9-2019-q4-major) 8.3.0.20190709-git
```

でした。

・試したこと
ここで、[ARMツールチェーンの新しい版(Zip)](https://developer.arm.com/-/media/Files/downloads/gnu/12.2.mpacbti-bet1/binrel/arm-gnu-toolchain-12.2.mpacbti-bet1-mingw-w64-i686-arm-none-eabi.zip)をダウンロード、解凍し、/opt/spresenseenv/usr/binのarm-none-eabi-gdb.exeをリネームして起動を止めてから新版のarm-none-eabi-gdb.exeからシンボリックリンクを張りました。この段階で、

```
$ arm-none-eabi-gdb --version
GNU gdb (Arm GNU Toolchain 12.2.MPACBTI-Bet1 (Build arm-12-mpacbti.16)) 13.0.50.20220406-git
```

となっています。
この状態から[デバッグの開始]を試みたところ、とりあえずソースレベルデバッグができました(ステップ実行しか試していません)。

・ちょっとだけ調査
同様の症例がないかと'vscode gdb major version'でググるとNordicでも[こんなの(2022/8)](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/91447/can-t-debug-ncs1-9-1-because-gdb-major-version-should-be-9)とか[こんなの(2022/9)](https://devzone.nordicsemi.com/f/nordic-q-a/92010/gdb-and-vscode-windows-not-working-after-gdb-version-8-forced-upgrade-to-version-9)も引っかかるので、VSCode本体かあるいは拡張のバージョンが上がってGDBバージョンの要求が厳しくなったということかと考えていますが...

ということで、
・公式サポートへの調査お願いと、
・とりあえずの対応として先のシンボリックリンクって有りなの? あるいは他の手段は? というあたりをご存じの方がいらっしゃれば伺いたく思います。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こんにちは。
私も同様のエラーが発生してしまったので、Cortex-Debugのバージョンを下げて対応しています。
Cortex-Debugのバージョンを1.4.4にするとデバッグできるようです。

公式なコンパイラのバージョン更新までは thkana さんのような方法か、Cortex-Debugのバージョンを下げるかの方法をとる必要がありそうですね。

Comment: > Cortex-Debugのバージョンを1.4.4にする
gdbだけバージョンを上げるよりもこちらの方が順当に思えます。SDKの対応まではそちらで...と試してみようとしたら、OpenOCDがなんだか繋がらなくなってるのはなんなんだろう?
とりあえずありがとうございました。

Comment: USBドライバ周り?で怪しい挙動もありますが(しばしばデバイスを削除/再登録してやらないとOpenOCDがデバッガを認識してくれない)それは別の話として、Cortex-Debugのバージョンを下げることでSpresense SDK(IDE)でGDBを起動し、Hello Worldレベルのプログラムのデバッグ(とりあえずステップ実行が)できました。ありがとうございました。

Comment: ちなみに、MCU-Linkはデバッガとして使えましたが秋月のLPC11U35ボードはダメみたいです。Spresense SDKとは別途用意したOpenOCD 0.11.0では認識するので、今後に期待したりしますが...

Answer (score 1):

こんにちは。
最近公式のSpresenseSDKとSpresenseVSCodeIDEが更新され、GDB versionエラーが発生しなくなったので報告します。
SpresenseSDK v3.0.0とSpresenseVSCodeIDEのバージョン「v1.4.100」が、3月13日にリリースされたようで、そのバージョンのinstall-tools.shを使って下記リリースノートの手順でツールチェーンを更新すると
GCCのクロスコンパイラのバージョンが10.3.1に更新されるようです。
[v3.0.0リリースノート](https://github.com/sonydevworld/spresense/releases/tag/v3.0.0)
また、SDKとIDE共にそのバージョンにアップデートするとGDBのバージョンエラーが起きなくなりました。
thkana さんもアップデートすると問題解決すると思います。

ご参考になれば幸いです。